# edX platform Spanish localization

Tags: console, gettext, platform, edx

I have already installed edX platform in my computer, but I want to translate it to Spanish. Also, I have discovered that `www.transifex.com` has just translated ed X into Spanish (Latino).
But when I'm installing this https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Internationalization-and-localization , at the point that I execute:

```
rake i18n:generate
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot locate GNU get text utilities, which are required by django for internationalization.
(*see docs.django project.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files*). Try downloading them from http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/
```

I am completely lost, because i have downloaded get text, but there is no get text-utils folder, and I have created it but still doesn't work.

I'm working on a Mac Console.

Thank you in advance,

ehe.

Answer (score 0):

Did You try this ?

```
$ rake i18n:generate -t
```

I've Found that command at this manual:
http://edx.asmoz.org/pdf/instalacion.pdf

Greetings